# How to step through each file and resolve conflict after an update in TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

This is likely very easy to solve but it's not documented anywhere, AFAIK. I've updated my local repository and there are conflicts. I now have exclamations marks showing me the conflicted files but the repo is huge so I want TortoiseSvn to show me or step me through conflicted files, how do I do that?

There's an option in the context menu 'Resolve...'

[image]

I cannot find any mention of what this command does, however. Either in the help contents or online. What is this command for? (I don't want to try it without knowing what it does because TortoiseSVN isn't very forgiving). As I say, I've searched for information online and through the help contents with no success. I'm running TortoiseSVN version 1.8.8.

Comment: 5s of [google shows the page](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html): "You can use the Resolved command for multiple files if you right click on the parent folder and select TortoiseSVN → Resolved... This will bring up a dialog listing all conflicted files in that folder, and you can select which ones to mark as resolved."

Comment: The command I circled says 'Resolve' not 'Resolved'. If it's the same thing then one or the other should be changed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, menu items that end with `…` imply that they don't make any immediate action but, instead, open a dialogue. So it should be safe to click on it. Additionally, when in doubt you can always copy your entire working copy directory and try whatever you want there; changes won't be uploaded to the repository unless you explicitly commit them.

Said that, the *Resolve* menu opens a handy dialogue that offers some resolution alternatives. Those differ depending on the conflict type, and it's sometimes slow because it connects to the repository to gather further info, but file conflicts always include a choice to resolve manually using the configured editor or you can just dismiss the dialogue and fix conflict files manually.

As about the question title, the *Check for modifications* dialogue should be your workhorse for this and most others working copy operations. Among others, it shows conflicts and allows to double-click on them to display the *Resolve* dialogue.